# It'd be an adventure!

Tags: will-would

In the trailer of "First man", there is a conversation between Neil and his wife:
Neil: Are you sure?
Janet: Yes, **it'd be** an adventure.

I guess, they are making a decision to allow Neil for the voyage to the moon. I wonder why she used "would" insted of "will" because I guess she meant: "Go for it, it will be worth it". Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 1):

They are in the process of deciding. She might have said.

"Yes, if you were to stay at home, you would be disappointed but if you went it would be an adventure."